# Keeping same Puppeteer page open nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm working on an API developed around running some JS on a page that's opened in Puppeteer but I don't want to keep open/closing & waiting for the page to load since it's a heavy content page.

Is it possible to run a `forever start` on a node script that initiates the page & keeps it open forever & then call a separate node script whenever it's needed to run some javascript on this page?

I've attempted the following but appears the page doesn't remain open:

**keepopen.js**

```
'use strict';
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
    const start = +new Date();
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.bigwebsite.com/', {"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"});
    const end =  +new Date();
    console.log(end - start);
    //await browser.close();
})();
```

**runjs.js**

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
    const start = +new Date();
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.targets()[browser.targets().length-1].page();
    const hash = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return runFunction();
    });
    const end =  +new Date();
    console.log(hash);
    console.log(end - start);
    //await browser.close();
})();
```

I run the following: `forever start keepopen.js` and then `runjs.js` but I'm getting the error:

```
(node:1642) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'evaluate' of null
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to share a resource between two Node.js scripts like that. You need a server that keeps the browser open.

**Code Sample**

Below is an example, using the library [express](https://expressjs.com/) to start a server. Calling `/start-browser` launches the browser and stores the browser and page object outside of the current function. That way a second function (called when `/run` is accessed) can use the `page` object to run code inside of it.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

let browser, page;

app.get('/start-browser', async function (req, res) {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
    page = await browser.newPage();
    res.end('Browser started');
});

app.get('/run', async function (req, res) {
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        // ....
    });
    res.end('Done.'); // You could also return results here
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Keep in mind, that this a minimal example to get you started. In a real world scenario, you would need to catch errors and maybe also restart the browser from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a http server, using node, where the puppeteer `page` object is created once on startup, and then initiate your current script by placing that code inside (a so called) "routing" function (which is just a function that serves a web request) of the http server you've created.

As long as the `page` object is created right outside the scope of the routing function, that contains your code, your routing function will maintain access to that same `page` object between numerous web requests.

You'll be able to reuse that same `page` object over and over again instead having to reload it for each call like you're currently doing. However, you need a service to persist the `page` object between requests/calls.

You can either create your own http server (using node's built-in http package), or use `express` (and there are many other http based packages besides `express` you could use).